# How can I install Ubuntu alongside Fedora?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I am currently running Fedora and would like to dual boot Fedora with Ubuntu. I do not want to replace Fedora, I would like to keep it as my main OS. However, when using the Ubuntu installer I only get the options to either: "Replace Fedora release 20 (Heisenbug) with Ubuntu" or "Something else".

Is there a way I can install Ubuntu alongside Fedora without deleting it? If so, as I would like Fedora to be my main OS, is there also a way to make it the top Grub option?

I have tried partitioning with Gparted, however I can't split the Fedora partition. It says it is all used, however I have only used about 100GB/500GB.

I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 using a live USB stick. I will upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 when I install it, but don't want to make a new Ubuntu live USB.

```
fdisk -l:    

Device    Boot     Start       End    Blocks  Id System
/dev/sda1 *         2048   1026047    512000  83 Linux
/dev/sda2        1026048 976773119 487873536  8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-swap: 3.8 GiB, 4043309056 bytes, 7897088 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-root: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-home: 411.5 GiB, 441848954880 bytes, 862986240 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

parted -l:

Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABF0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  525MB  524MB  primary  ext4         boot
 2      525MB   500GB  500GB  primary               lvm


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-home: 442GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  442GB  442GB  ext4


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-root: 53.7GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  53.7GB  53.7GB  ext4


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-swap: 4043MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  4043MB  4043MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

Comment: Boot from Fedora and issue the command `sudo fdisk -l` or `sudo parted -l` , then edit your question and add the additional info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that Ubuntu (automate) installer is able to detect and configure Logical Volume Manager setup. So, you have to use either Gparted or the lvm tools (e.g. from inside Fedora, or Ubuntu Live CD) in order to shrink the partition and leave some space for Ubuntu and then use the "something else" option to install Ubuntu.

Of course Ubuntu can be installed in a logical partition and if Gparted don't allow you to shrink the partition (because it is "used" as you said) this could be because of the swap partition that automatically mounted even if you boot from a Live image.

So, (assumed that you use the Gparted from Ubuntu Live CD)

- Boot from the LiveCD/USB and click on "Try Ubuntu".
- Open Gparted, then right click on swap partition and swapoff.
- Shrink the biggest partition(right click and resize) and leave some space for Ubuntu. Create a new logical partition.
- Close Gparted and begin the installation.
- Click on "something else" and there you must see the new created partition.
- Click there and then click on "Change" in order to use the partition (create an ext4 filesytem and mount it on root /).

About the second part of your question:

> If so, as I would like Fedora to be my main OS, is there also a way
>   to make it the top Grub option?

After the installation finish (with no errors), Ubuntu Grub will replace Fedora Grub in Disk's MBR. And so, you will have Ubuntu as main OS in Grub list. In order to replace Ubuntu Grub with Fedora Grub again, you must boot on Fedora and give the following command

```
sudo grub2-install --recheck /dev/sda
```

Above command will reinstall Fedora Grub in Disk's MBR, so everything will back to "normal" (I mean as you already have it, with Fedora as fist OS in Grub list...etc).

*(at the moment, I'm not able to add a tutorial-like answer here, with pictures..etc. If someone is, feel free to edit this answer an make it better for everyone.)*